# How do I return a list of integers using a VB.NET function?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am working on a report in SSRS2005 where I need to use some VB.NET code to go out to a different database than the one in the report and return a list of integers (user IDs).  I need to use some VB.NET code to do this.  I have some code that 'works' in the sense that it does not throw any errors and I get values returned.  However, I only get the first value and not the entire list.  Here is what I have so far:

```
Public Function GetUsers(ByVal param As Integer) As String
Dim sqlCon As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
Dim dRet As String
Dim sCmdText As String

sqlCon.ConnectionString = "data source=myServer;initial catalog=myDatabase;Integrated Security=true"


cmd = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
sCmdText = "SELECT UsersRowID FROM dbo.tvf_Get_Users(" 
'cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Connection = sqlCon
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0

sCmdText = sCmdText & param
sCmdText = sCmdText & ")"

cmd.CommandText = sCmdText
If sqlCon.State <> System.Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
sqlCon.Open()
End If
dRet = cmd.ExecuteScalar() & ""     
sqlCon.Close()

Return dRet

End Function
```

I have tried experimenting with using the DataSet data type but I get error messages that I cannot cast DataSet as a String.

Any ideas what I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: `ExecuteScalar` always returns just one value.  That's what "scalar" means.  Have a look at http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Forming-Comma-Separated-String-in-SQL-Server-428.php

Comment: if you use ExecuteScalar it will return only one value, try SqlDataAdapter with DataSet or DataReader

Comment: Thank you Robert.  That was it exactly.  It works now.

Answer (score 0):

modify your code to the following

```
Public Function GetUsers(ByVal param As Integer) As String
'
Dim sqlCon As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
Dim dtAdapter As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
Dim dRet As String
Dim sCmdText As String
'
  'connection
  sqlCon.ConnectionString = "data source=myServer;initial catalog=myDatabase;Integrated Security=true"
  sqlCon.Open()
  '
  'query
  sCmdText = "SELECT UsersRowID FROM dbo.tvf_Get_Users(" & param & ")"
  '
  'command
  cmd = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sCmdText, sqlCon)
  cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
  '
  'main course
  If cmd.Connection.State = Data.ConnectionState.Closed Then cmd.Connection.Open()
  dtAdapter = cmd.ExecuteReader(Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
  If dtAdapter.HasRows Then
    While dtAdapter.Read()
      ' following assumes "dbUserId" is the userid field in the database 
      ' also use pipe "|" to split the userid's whens theres more than one
      ' this is so you can still use STRING as the function return and not an ARRAY
      dRet = dRet & dtAdapter.GetValue(dtAdapter.GetOrdinal("dbUserId")) & "|"
    End While
  End If
  If cmd.Connection.State <> Data.ConnectionState.Closed Then cmd.Connection.Close()
  Return dRet
  '
End Function
```